# How do I load fields using fields_for :symbol - but only render the form field for the final object that the symbol references?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have a `Category` model that `has_many` `Skills`.

I have a page where I want a user to be able to add a single new `skill` to a selected `category` via a textbox (just the name of the `skill`), while listing all existing on a page `categories` and the `skills` within those `categories`.

I can currently display all the `categories` with their contained `skills`, but **I'm not sure how to make it so a user can only create a new `skill` without being able to edit all the other `skills`** that `belongs_to` a `category`.

Here is the code that I have currently:

**Controller:**

```
def show
  . . .
  #needed for showing all categories
  @categories = current_user.categories
  #needed to show a blank skill when editing a category
  @skills = []
  @categories.each do |cat|
    @skills << cat.skills.build
  end
  . . .
end
```

**View:**

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %> # I skip most of the code related to formatting
    <%= simple_form_for(category) do |f| %>
      <%= f.fields_for :skills do |s| %>
        <div class="inputs">
          <%= s.input :name %> 
          <%= s.hidden_field :category_id %>
          <%= s.hidden_field :id %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
          <%= f.button :submit %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And it ultimately results in a form that looks like this:

[image: able to edit every skill]

I have tried to change `f.fields_for :skills` to `f.fields_for category.skills.last`(because the last object in `category.skills` is a new skill that was created in the controller) and this results in a blank text box that looks like what I need:

[image: Only renders the blank skill field, but cannot submit it]

But when I submit the form, I get a "*param not found: category*" error (that points to my params.require(:category). . . line in my Category controller.

I'm not sure why the form works if I use the symbol for `:skills` but doesn't work when I use `category.skills.last` (or even `category.skills.each` - I get a different error when I do that: *undefined method `model_name' for Enumerator:Class*).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Share your server's log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TRY THIS**
`f.fields_for :skills, category.skills.last`

`:skills` represents relation name. (`category has many skills`)

`category.skills.last` represents the object that you want to use in form. 
e.g

```
f.fields_for :skills, category.skills.build do |s| .. end
```

or

```
f.fields_for :skills, category.skills.last(3) do |s| ... end
```

Comment: `f.fields_for :skills, category.skills.build do |s| .. end` allowed for a cleaner controller as well (the messy version was not included above).